# String in set of pandas dataframe but not in selected column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, python-3.6

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns has a uniform datatype of string, and for a specific string I wanted to check if it was in that column. I found the simple comparison gave 'False', but after checking the dataframe itself I verified that the specific string was indeed in that column. On the other hand, if I convert the selected column to a set I get the expected behaviour.

```
>>> 'string' in df['col_name']
False
>>> 'string' in set(df['col_name'])
True
```

1. Why do pandas dataframes have this behaviour?
2. Is the a conventional way to check if an object is in a pandas dataframe column?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data in `df['col_name']` that returns this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn the `df['col_name']` into a list of the values. Currently, it is a `series` object.

try `'string' in df['col_name'].values`.

`'string' in df['col_name']` is searching the `index` of the series

Answer (score 0):

`'string' in df['col_name']` is translated to `df['col_name'].__contains__('string')`. `Series.__contains__` method will check on series index, Not on value.

Below is the implement of series `__contains__` in `lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py`

> ```
> def __contains__(self, key):
>     """True if the key is in the info axis"""
>     return key in self._info_axis
> ```

info axis is the index.

---

You need to use `in` on the ndarray value of the series.